# iOS Swift: Pass data from ViewController to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass data from a ViewController to a custom UITableViewCell but it's not working. When I print `data` from `ViewController.swift` everything is in tact but when I print `data` from `CustomCell.swift` the array is empty. Here is my code:

ViewController.swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier) as! CustomCell
    cell.data = data[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

CustomCell.swift

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var data = [CKRecord]()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        println(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: The cell's init method runs before you set the data in the line, cell.data = data[indexPath.row], so, of course the data will print as nil there. The cell shouldn't be storing data anyway; that's not the job of a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `CustomCell.swift`, you just have to set the content such as: `UILabel`, `UIImage`, etc.

Rather than explaining here the whole things, I think you better follow the tutorial here:
http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/prototype-cells-tableview-tutorial-ios8-swift

if you have more time, this is the deeper one :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/81879/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-1

good luck! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can perform that simply by using `didSet` closure, change your code to the following:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var data = [Int]() {
        didSet{
            print(data)
        }
    }
    
    var id: Int {
        didSet{
            loadById(id)
        }
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // This block runs before data being set! Rather call your code from didSet{} closure..
    }
    
    
    func loadById(_ id: Int) {
        // Your code goes here
    }
    
}
```

And from your ViewController pass the data:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomCell
    
    cell.data = data[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.id = 1 // pass here any variable you need
    
    return cell
}
```

And it should work